# How to get all collection names of database(mongodb) in nodejs using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to console.log all collections of a database(default test)

I found below solution but its not working.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test',)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Database Connected");
        mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray((error, collections) => {
            collections.forEach((collection) => {
                console.log(collection.name);
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log("Database connection Failed");
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working"? No error message? You did not process any error in your array. It always bad to print a static text like `"Database connection Failed"` because then you hide all relevant information of this error.

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try using map instead of forEach

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test',)
.then(() => {
    console.log("Database Connected");
    mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray((error, collections) => {
        if (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving collections:', error);
    return;
  }

  // Extract collection names from the collections array
  const collectionNames = collections.map(collection => collection.name);
  console.log('Collection Names:', collectionNames);
    });
})
.catch(() => {
    console.log("Database connection Failed");
});
```

if error, check it what the issue. mostly it will be connecting with db